# Can I disable a global response assertion from selected samplers in JMeter script?

Tags: jmeter

I have come through a situation where I have declared the same text in the Global response assertion but that text is being returned for few of the HTTP samplers(occasional not always which I have to ignore). Now I want my jmeter script to be written in such a way that the global assertion should be there but  it can be disabled for few of the samplers. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by going for the below approach:

1. Insert a regular expression extractor in the sampler where there are chances to get the unexpected response(which is present in the global assertion and because of which the samplers are failing).
2. Use the BeanShell PostProcessor with below code to over-write the response. so that global assertion should not be applied on the actual response.

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

   //Exception_RE is the Refernce Name for the regular exception extractor for Exception.
   if(${__javaScript(vars.get('Exception_RE_matchNr')>=1,)}) {

   String DefaultResponse = "My Test Response on Exception"; 

   //To over-write the sampler response with the our own response message when we encounter the Exception which is there in the global assertion.
   prev.setResponseData(DefaultResponse);


   prev.setResponseOK();

   }
   ```

Comment: You can format your code in your post with highlighting the code and pressing Ctrl+K. This makes code more easily readable. Thank you!